# Split a string before the first number

Tags: php, regex, split, digits, preg-split

I would like to split a string like this:

```
Mystreetway 123, 1.th
```

So that I can have the following output array:

```
0 => Mystreetway
1 => 123, 1.th
```

The code must split the string before the first integer found.  The substring from the first integer to the end of the string should become the second element upon splitting

I have tried the following found solution:

```
$key = "Mystreetway 123, 1.th";
$pattern = "/(\d+)/";

$array = preg_split($pattern, $key, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($array);
```

But it returns the following:

```
[0] => Mystreetway [1] => 123 [2] => , [3] => 1 [4] => .th
```

Answer (score 6):

Split with a lookahead pattern instead (so you won't have to juggle captured delimiters), then limit the number of groups to just two (with third param of `preg_split`:

```
$key= "Mystreetway 123, 1.th";
$pattern = '/(?=\d)/';

$array = preg_split($pattern, $key, 2);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a lookahead assertion to match a zero-width (empty) expression before a digit:

```
/(?=\d)/
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you're looking for is `limit`. Change your third parameter from `-1` (meaning, split as many times as necessary) to `1` (meaning, split only once) and the string will be split on the first integer.

```
$key= "Mystreetway 123, 1.th";
$pattern = "/(\d+)/";

$array = preg_split($pattern, $key, 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($array);
```

**Edit: For your case, this doesn't actually work, but if we change your regular expression slightly it works as desired;**

```
$key= "Mystreetway 123, 1.th";
$pattern = "/(\d.*)/"; // Note we're now looking for a digit followed by anything

$array = preg_split($pattern, $key, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mystreetway
    [1] => 123, 1.th
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_match

`preg_match('/(\D*)(\d*.*)/', $input_line, $output_array);`

Output

```
array(3
0   =>  Mystreetway 123, 1.th
1   =>  Mystreetway 
2   =>  123, 1.th
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the cleanest output, with no lookaround, match all leading non-digit characters, then forget them with `\K`, then consume the unneeded space character before the first occurring digit.  Limit the explosions to only produce 2 elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3DiqC))

```
$string = "Mystreetway 123, 1.th";

var_export (
    preg_split('/\D+\K /', $string, 2)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Mystreetway',
  1 => '123, 1.th',
)
```